# Does Google consider deep URLs with and without a trailing slash to be the same?

Tags: seo, google, google-ranking, trailing-slash

Will it hit my ranking if I have the same URLs where `/` on the end is the only difference?

Those URLs return the same content and one redirects to another or they both redirects to some 3rd URL.

These URLs are all in canonical tags on the page.

Do I need to have both `www.example.com/asdf` and `www.example.com/asdf/`
in the canonical, can that situation hit my ranking?